# Migrate to Ventura and put one user's home directory on a different drive

Tags: ventura, migration, migration-assistant

I just bought a new Mac Mini to replace my old one. I have a user account I'd like to migrate, but there isn't space on the new Mac Mini's internal hard drive. Can I migrate that user so that their home directory is on an external drive? Thanks!

Comment: Are there directories in the home directory (Movies for instance) which are taking up the lion share of the size? If yes, you could off-load them to an external drive *before* the migration, delete them on the old Mac and then migrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the location of your user domain to another drive, but bear in mind that if that location is unavailable at startup, the OS will create a new EMPTY user account at the default on-board location, **with the same user name**.

I would therefore recommend just moving your Documents and media files, but leaving the 'business end' of the user account (Library), in place.

In System Settings > Users & Groups, right-click on the User, and click on Advanced Options. This includes the location. You will need to restart.

[image]

Comment: I just took a look, and I only have a an option to move the entire Home directory, not specific directories.

Are you suggesting the following:

1. Create a user hselden on the destination machine with the same user ID as the source machine
2. Change hselden's Home directory per above
3. Move hselden's Library back to /Users/hselden/Library 
4. Migrate hselden's data using the migration tool

Thanks!

Comment: Also, to be clear, hselden is not the user's real name :)

Comment: @BeccaDee I'm suggesting that you don't migrate your Documents, and then copy them separately to an external drive.

Comment: Thank you. After some thinking, I may do something totally different, but this would solve the problem I originally posed.